# Flex: Delete item from collection bound to datagrid and update the grid selected index

Tags: apache-flex, collections, datagrid

I have a datagrid with an xmlListCollection bound to it:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgCompetente" includeIn="Competente" x="10" y="66" width="547" height="468"
                 change="dgCompetente_changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{colCompetente}"
                 editable="false">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="ID Competenţă" dataField="idCompetenta"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Denumire Competenţă" dataField="denCompetenta"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Competenţă Superioară" dataField="idCompSuperioara" labelFunction="labelFunctionCompetentaSuperioara"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
```

and a button to delete the currently selected item in the datagrid, which has this function assigned to the click event:

```
<s:Button id="btnDeleteCompetenta" includeIn="Competente" x="813" y="65" label="Stergere" click="deleteCompetenta()"/>


private function deleteCompetenta():void 
{
    try {
        var position:int = dgCompetente.selectedIndex;

        if (position >= 0) {
            colCompetente.removeItemAt(position);
            dgCompetente.selectedIndex = position;
        }

        clearEdit(fieldsCompetente);
        saveCompetente();
    } catch (error:Error) {
        errorHandler.defaultErrorHandler(error);
    }
}
```

I want the selectedIndex to remain the same. So, if I delete item 2, the next in the list should be selected. The problem is that if I delete item 2, item 3 will be selected and I have no idea why.

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably resetting the selectedIndex too early, before the DataGrid is updated, but it's hard to tell exactly since your code calls a bunch of functions.  Try this

Add a "cached position" variable, like this:

```
protected var cachedPosition : int;
```

Then modify your deleteCompetenta method

```
private function deleteCompetenta():void 
{
    try {
        cachedPosition = dgCompetente.selectedIndex;

        if (position >= 0) {
            colCompetente.removeItemAt(position);
//            don't reset this here
//            dgCompetente.selectedIndex = position;
        }

        clearEdit(fieldsCompetente);
        saveCompetente();
    } catch (error:Error) {
        errorHandler.defaultErrorHandler(error);
    }
}
```

Then add an updateCompleteHander to the DataGrid:

```
<mx:DataGrid id="dgCompetente" includeIn="Competente" x="10" y="66" width="547" height="468"
                 change="dgCompetente_changeHandler(event)" dataProvider="{colCompetente}"
                 editable="false" updateComplete="updateCompleteHandler(event)">
```

And reset the selectedIndex int he updateCompleteHandler:

```
protected function updateCompleteHandler(event:Event):void{
// reset here
 dgCompetente.selectedIndex = cachedPosition;
}
```

Would that solve it?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work selectedIndex don't update with the good value also in updateCompleteHandler
but with value-1 if force value+1, take value+2 and the selection escape from click, so it's exactly the same.